# Python Pillow / PIL image processing

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm currently working on some image processing. But I don't understand a few things.

First quesiton is about `ImageEnhance` module. [This](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageEnhance.html) is the link for the documentation. If I understand it correctly I have to create an object for each operation I'd like to do:

```
# Enhance sharpness
sharpness = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(image)
image = sharpness.enhance(1.0)

# Enhance contrast
contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
image = contrast.enhance(1.0)
```

Or is there a possibility to use only one object for enhancing multiple things.

My second question is about the `ImageOps` module. [Documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageOps.html). I'm trying to use the `autocontrast` method but I'm getting the error `not supported for this image mode`. I tried to find an explanation but I can't find which *Image mode* is necessary or how to change/fix the error. An example code would be:

```
img = ImageOps.autocontrast(img)
```

I'd really appreciate some insights and hints.

Comment: To your first question: I think it's easily possible to write a function or class that encapsulates multiple image enhancement classes and runs multiple steps. To question number two: The documentation states at the top "most operators only work on L and RGB images". Make sure to use these modes. Others are listed [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).

Comment: Please don't ask two different questions in a single question. Your problems with `ImageEnhance` should go in one question, and your problems with `ImageOps` should be posted in a separate question.